# How to pass touch event from parent view to child view

Tags: android, multi-touch, android-viewgroup, childviews

I am writing an code to handle touch event based on what suggested [here](http://neevek.net/posts/2013/10/13/implementing-onInterceptTouchEvent-and-onTouchEvent-for-ViewGroup.html). Basically I wanted to pass touch event back to child view from parent view. Following what I did and remaining.

**What I need**

1. Detect multitouch event on child view: DONE
2. then pass touch control to parent: DONE
3. Now Detect if multitouch removed from parent: DONE
4. Then pass control back to child view: **REMAIN**.

Any suggestion here.